# Having trouble with Django and adding to tables

Tags: python, django

I was following a tutorial on youtube and it came to a point where we were putting data on tables on the admin site.

This is the link with the time stamp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uQrJ0TkZlc&t=20490s

when I finished with the info it brings up this error message

> OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
>
> **no such table: main.auth_user__old**

btw im on MacOs Catalina

```
django = 2.1
python = 3.8
```

Anything I can do?

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command?

Comment: @shafik yes I did

Comment: Can you add your model and admin code here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this problem:

1. Delete db.sqlite3 file in your root folder
2. Go to migrations folder of your app and delete all the migrations files. eg: 0001_initial.py etc
3. python3 manage.py makemigrations
4. python3 manage.py migrate
5. python3 manage.py createsuperuser

This should work for you